# Toolbox Disabled in Visual Studio Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, toolbox

So I decided to learn some Win32 programming in C++ and thought i will try adding the controls from the toolbox and tada!! no tools there. Even if i try to choose the Com controls manually it still doesn't get shown. If i do Show All , i can see all the tools are disabled even the ones i selected.

I have seen and tried almost all of the solutions seen on the internet (reset toolbox, remove the tbd files, remove reg keys, fresh installation etc) to no avail.

I was using VS2012 Express initially but I have also tried a fresh installation of VC++ 2010 Express with the same result.

So I have two questions:
1) Are the tools not supposed to be there in an Express installation?
2) If they are supposed to be there could someone help me with fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. The Express editions don't support building GUI applications in C++. All of the controls in the toolbox require .NET. You'll need to create a new project of the appropriate type using C# or Visual Basic to use any of the controls.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I was thinking that might be the case.

Comment: Is there a way to compile RC files in Express? or is that also not supported? I know the Resource editor is not there so just wondering

Comment: I'm not sure support is integrated in the IDE by default, but if nothing else the command line resource compiler `RC.EXE` should installed with the bundled Windows SDK. Look in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits" or "C:\Program Files (x86)\Micrsoft SKDs\Windows" directories.